# Failed to update to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) from ver 1703

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709

I have been trying to update to Windows 10 Fall Creators update (ver-1709) using the windows update option in settings.

After waiting for an hour or so to prepare, download and install the update, it fails with the following error.

> Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709 - Error 0x80d02002

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any idea how to fix this?

I currently run Windows 10 ver-1703.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by some incompatible software. This was detected by windows update, after applying the Microsoft [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/build-10074-error-0x80d02002/8ec7e4e5-1f00-4dc7-b441-9d6ad2c6288d) as [mentioned by harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1260164/16858).

[image: Incompatible software]

Comment: Why can't window update clearly give what exactly the issue is.. in case it did not find the downloaded components, it could silently re-get it from net and avoid users from download of full 1 gb software again..It can save tonnes of time and bandwidth to all of us

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft stock [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/build-10074-error-0x80d02002/8ec7e4e5-1f00-4dc7-b441-9d6ad2c6288d) is as follows.

> **Method 1:**
>
> You may try these steps to reset the Windows update components
>   manually and check.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on the desktop screen of the computer.
> 2. Select **Command Prompt (Admin)**
> 3. On the open Command Prompt window copy and paste the commands :
>
>    ```
>    net stop wuauserv
>    net stop cryptSvc
>    net stop bits
>    net stop msiserver
>    ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
>    ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old
>    net start wuauserv
>    net start cryptSvc
>    net start bits
>    net start msiserver
>    ```
> 4. Exit the command prompt and check.

Delete the renamed folders if everything is correct.

> You can try the following step if the issue persists.
>
> **Method 2:**
>
> Check if the region is correct. Follow the steps mentioned.
>
> 1. Type "**Region**" on the Start screen. Click "**Settings**" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. On the "**Format**" tab, select "**English (United Kingdom)**".
> 3. Click "**Languages Preferences**"> "**Add a language**" and add "your language".
> 4. Once added, select it and click "**Move Up**" to make it the first language. Close the Language window.
> 5. On the "**Region**" window, click "**Additional Settings**" and check if the values are same.
> 6. Click the "**Location**" tab and change the Home Location to "your country" and then click **OK**.